# Excel - Test for Overlapping Regions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that has a chart for several different objects that lists the location of their left edge, right edge, top, and bottom relative to a point in the top left corner. I want to make a condition for formatting the cell containing the object as red whenever one of the areas it creates overlaps any of the other areas.For instance, if:

......................**Object 1:**............**Object 2**............**Object 3:**
Left Edge:........... 2 ........................0.......................3
Right Edge: .........6.........................2.......................8
Top: ....................1........................10......................8
Bottom: ...............6 .......................12 .....................8

Then **Object 1** and **Object 3** would light up red, since they overlap, but **Object 2** would remain unlit, since it doesn't overlap anything else anywhere. I have made a program that successfully does this by OR-ing a long list of AND statements (three AND statements for every edge of every object) for each Object, but this is very messy, time-consuming, prone to errors, and is completely impractical for more than 4 objects. Is there a better way? If anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The bottom of Object 1 is 4 and the top of Object 3 is 5, is this what you intended? Right now I'm not visualizing them overlapping, but sharing different parts of the same columns (col 3-6).

Comment: I apologize; I made a mistake. It should be fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Is an Excel macro an acceptable solution to your problem? Some folks may not be able to use them because of active directory applied group policies.

Comment: I am rather new to Excel, so I have no experience with Macros. If there is an easy Macro solution, I'd love to use it, but I will need some extra help with the implementation.

Comment: In writing the VBA macro I'm running into a few things that need clarification. Are the numbers in the same cell, or in the cell to the right of the label? Can this be run as a keystroke after selecting the range containing the Objects to check for overlap? Does it need to act like conditional formatting?

Comment: It can act as a keystroke and it doesn't need to act like conditional formatting. Is there any way to add a chart to the post? For now, I added a make-shift chart that shows what it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VBA macro can do what you are looking for. On Windows Alt+F11 will bring up the VBA editor.

The general pseudo code to follow would be:

- with the selection grab the first row
- clear the highlight format from it
- use `For Each` to walk horizontally across it
- with each Object store the values for the 4 cells below it in named variables
- then in an inner loop compare these values to all of the Objects to the right
- comparison would logical and together horizontal and vertical overlap tests
- mark both cells if there is an overlap

Using this method if you have 10 boxes you check 45 pairs rather than 100 (10*10)

Answer (score 0):

Something else to consider:

```
Sub DetectOverlaps()
  Const OBJECTCOUNT As Long = 3
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  Dim ArrObj1 As Variant, ArrObj2 As Variant
  Dim Object1 As Range, Object2 As Range
  Debug.Print: Debug.Print
  For i = 1 To OBJECTCOUNT - 1
    j = i + 1
    While j <= OBJECTCOUNT
      ArrObj1 = Range("A1").Offset(1, i).Resize(4, 1)
      ArrObj2 = Range("A1").Offset(1, j).Resize(4, 1)
      Set Object1 = CoordinatesToRange(ArrObj1)
      Set Object2 = CoordinatesToRange(ArrObj2)

      Debug.Print "checking " & i & "-" & j, Object1.Address & " vs. " & Object2.Address,
      If Application.Intersect(Object1, Object2) Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "  -->ok"
      Else
        Debug.Print "  -->COLLISION"
      End If
      j = j + 1
    Wend
  Next i
End Sub

Function CoordinatesToRange(RangeAsArray As Variant) As Range
' RangeAsArray contains coordinates, in order: left, right, top, bottom
  Set CoordinatesToRange = Cells(RangeAsArray(3, 1) + 1, RangeAsArray(1, 1) + 1).Resize(RangeAsArray(4, 1) - RangeAsArray(3, 1) + 1, RangeAsArray(2, 1) - RangeAsArray(1, 1) + 1)
End Function
```

This makes use of the `Application.Intersect` method to detect overlapping ranges (which are built from rectangular coordinates). The ranges are not really meaningful here, but as long as the coordinates are between 0 and the max allowable row/column in your version of Excel, this will tell if there is a collision between any two range pairs.

I've assumed your definition of "Objects" is rooted at `A1` and has one row and one column header. The constant at the top is just cheap code to specify the number of Objects of interest; you can vary to suit or perhaps make this dynamic in your application.